# What Contemporary Philosophers Believe in the Thing-in-Itself?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics

What modern and contemporary philosophers believe in Kant's concept of the thing-in-itself, that which is inaccessible to the human experience. To me, this idea does not hold up except in a trivial sense, but I have not studied the categories well enough yet to determine for myself. However, I was wondering if there are major philosophers today who adhere to this concept and include it in their theory of Metaphysics or Epistemology.

Comment: None on Kant's original conception. Some reconceptualize it, e.g. phenomenologists as "*transempirical reality*", see [Adams](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2953804), and speculative realists as "*not something “unknowable to humans”*", but "*the excess in things beyond any of their relations to each other*", see [Harman](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/opphil-2020-0009/html). Before offering his reinterpretation, Harman notes Kant's influence and makes a telling remark:"*Even so, vanishingly few people today are willing to accept Kant’s central idea: the thing-in-itself*".

Comment: In the sense given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noumenon#The_noumenon_as_a_limiting_concept) : "the concept of a noumenon is necessary, to prevent sensible intuition from being extended to things in themselves, and thus to limit the objective validity of sensible knowledge." (Critique of Pure Reason, A253/B310) Kant used the concept of the noumenon to prevent undue assumptions.  Nietzsche dismissed the noumenon as [absurd](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/52915/52915-h/52915-h.htm#Page_65), preferring [perspectivity](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/52915/52915-h/52915-h.htm#Page_13).

Comment: @Conifold Great, so the original thesis, it seems like very few people nowadays believe or defend. If this is so, why was the argument against "correlationism" such as in Quentin Meillassoux's "After Finitude" such a central thesis? Is it that maybe this original conception was used as a strawman in the early days of the Speculative Realist movement?

Comment: Harman explains that too before offering his way out:"*But among the new realists and their fellow travelers, who accepts this thing-in-itself? Certainly not Ferraris or Gabriel, who reject it on principle as a barrier to knowledge; certainly not Meillassoux, who reduces the thing-in-itself to something that merely outlasts us in time... These admiring critics of Kant are no less taxonomical than the master himself. As we saw earlier, whether or not there is a “gap” between thought and world, the real problem is that thought and world are taken as the two basic terms in the first place.*"

Comment: @Conifold Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: I've always been wondering in what measure advances in modern science have influenced that debate, if they have influenced it at all. After all, physics explains that e.g. our eyes receive photons from distant objects who either produced them or reflected them... it seems there is less and less room for phenomena/noumena?

Comment: @Conifold Mind making a proper answer out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One wonders whether Kant himself "believed in" the *ding an sich*, or if they are of a kind of thing that *anyone* can "believe in." In a footnote (17) to the Transcendental Dialectic, Kant says:

> The question, "What is the constitution of a transcendental object?" is unanswerable—we are unable to say what it is; but we can perceive that the question itself **is nothing**; because it does not relate to any object that can be presented to us. For this reason, we must consider all the questions raised in transcendental psychology as answerable and as really answered; for they relate to the transcendental subject of all internal phenomena, which is not itself phenomenon and consequently not given as an object, in which, moreover, none of the categories—and it is to them that the question is properly directed—find any conditions of its application. Here, therefore, is a case where no answer is the only proper answer. For a question regarding the constitution of a something which cannot be cogitated by any determined predicate, being completely beyond the sphere of objects and experience, is **perfectly null and void**. [emphasis added]

Granted, elsewhere he writes:

> ... the sensuous internal intuition of the mind (as the object of consciousness), the determination of which is represented by the succession of different states in time, is not the real, proper self, as it exists in itself—not the transcendental subject—but only a phenomenon, which is presented to the sensibility of this, to us, unknown being. This internal phenomenon cannot be admitted to be a self-subsisting thing; for its condition is time, and time cannot be the condition of a thing in itself.

And one wonders what would happen to Kantian metaphysics of ethics without a more substantial doctrine of the *an sich* domain in place.

All that being said, we must be careful to distinguish the use of the term "things in themselves" from the term "things in general" (Kant does write of "things in general" at one point) and especially the term "noumena." For example, spacetime forms with different dimensionalities than we know of in our own experience, rather than spacetime-transcendent being altogether, would not be forms of intellectual intuition (the most "proper" sphere of things in themselves), yet neither of empirically corroborated intuition either. Yet then it is not entirely clear that Kant himself, much less his inheritors and critics, track such distinctions all too well, all of the time, and so in addition to the lack of content implicitly attributed by Kant to the term "thing in itself" in the footnote we opened this answer with, there seems to be a lack of stable content in the use of the term by others as well.

So it is not completely apparent that there even *is* a real doctrine of the *an sich* for anyone to agree or disagree with in the first place, or that attempts to carry on such a doctrine (if it exists!) from Kant to today are on the same page as Kant tried to write the book on.

Comment: What do you mean by "For example, spacetime forms with different dimensionalities than we know of in our own experience". Also, why would anyone defend or have a clear idea of such a position of the thing-in-itself if there is so much obfuscation in the term in the first place, today?

Comment: @TCoff, Kant says that space being 3-dimensional/time being 1-dimensional are synthetic facts. It would be logically possible for spacetime to be otherwise dimensionalized, and this is a sort of noumenal possibility. However, it would not be at all possible for space/time to be nonempirical forms of intuition; entirely nonempirical intuition, intellectual intuition, is not just noumenal, but is the domain of the in-itself. Why would anyone defend or disagree with Kant, here? People believe they are agreeing or disagreeing with each other all the time, without much self-understanding.

Comment: Consider that we are speaking of a roughly 500-page text (depending on how it's typeset), translated from a notoriously difficult language (German, and not even contemporary but late 18th-Century German), and which is about a subject (philosophy) from which labyrinths of thought are easily made, and much harder to navigate. And then we're dealing with arguably the most esoteric "doctrine" in the whole Kantian corpus (talk of things in themselves). I would be surprised to find that interpreters of Kant, or even Kant himself, were altogether consistent about their word usage, here.

Comment: These were very interesting insights. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Immanuel Kant proposed the concept of the thing-in-itself, also known as the "noumenon," in the 18th century as a way to explain the limits of human knowledge. According to Kant, the true nature of an object is the thing-in-itself, but it is unknowable to us because it is not directly accessible through our senses or forms of understanding. Instead, we can only know the appearances of objects as mediated by our senses and modes of comprehension.

Since Kant's time, philosophers have debated and discussed his concept of the thing-in-itself. Some philosophers accept the idea of an unknowable realm of reality beyond our experience, while others reject it as incompatible with our understanding of the world.

It is difficult to say definitively whether any contemporary philosophers share Kant's belief in the thing-in-itself. However, some philosophers continue to investigate the possibility that there are aspects of reality that are beyond the scope of human comprehension or that are not fully captured by our conceptual frameworks. David Chalmers, who has written about the concept of the "hard problem of consciousness," and Thomas Nagel, who has explored the limitations of human subjectivity in his work, are two philosophers who have engaged with this idea. It is important to note, however, that these philosophers may not necessarily support Kant's specific concept of the thing-in-itself.